# Issue with context data

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I'm trying to set the ApplicationIdData while sending message to a queue, using IBM MQ in java.

When I run the below code, the message is getting published to the queue as expected, but the ApplicationData received at the other receiver end is blank/empty.

```
int openOptions =  MQConstants.MQOO_SET_IDENTITY_CONTEXT | MQConstants.MQOO_OUTPUT | MQConstants.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF | MQConstants.MQOO_INQUIRE;
queue = mqManager.accessQueue(queueName, openOptions);
int putOptions =  MQConstants.MQPMO_ASYNC_RESPONSE;;
MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions();
pmo.options = putOptions;

MQMessage msg = new MQMessage();
msg.applicationIdData = "TestId";
msg.writeString(qmessage);

queue.put(msg, pmo);
```

I believe ApplicationIdData belongs to the Identity Context group. So, I tried using MQPMO_SET_IDENTITY_CONTEXT in the putOptions, but I keep gettin an error: "MQException: Reason 2095" and message does not even get published to the queue.
Any thoughts/suggestions please?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have +SETID on both the queue manage (qmgr) and the queue?  What version of MQ are your jar files from?

Comment: Hi @JoshMc, I'm not sure of about the +SETID config. I'm using 9.0.5.0 version of MQ. Thank you.

Comment: MQRC 2095 is MQRC_NOT_OPEN_FOR_SET_ALL which suggests that adding MQPMO_SET_IDENTITY_CONTEXT to your putOptions is being treated as if you added MQPMO_SET_ALL_CONTEXT. As a quick experiment, could you try doing the same again, but also change the openOptions to use MQOO_SET_ALL_CONTEXT. If that works, I would suggest contacting IBM by opening a case.

Comment: Thank you Morag for your inputs! it did help me!

Comment: Hi @Morag, any thoughts on my comment below regarding extra white spaces please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to use the MQPMO_SET_IDENTITY_CONTEXT put message option you also need to open the queue with the open option MQOO_SET_IDENTIY_CONTEXT:

"For the MQPUT call, the queue must have been opened with the MQOO_SET_IDENTITY_CONTEXT option" from
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/7.5?topic=f-options-mqlong-11

And of course the userid you are using to send this message will need the setid authority on the queue.

Comment: Hi @Attila, there is another issue...do we know why extra spaces are getting padded at the end of thre ApplicationIdData at the receiver end?i.e. the receiver gets the ApplicationIdData as "TestId        ". Is there something I (i.e. the client) can do to remove these? Thank you.

Comment: @Mitu - ApplicationIdData is an MQCHAR32 type, so you would expect the receiver to get all 32 characters. If you don't want it to be blank padded, you should ensure that the string you place in the field is null terminated.

Comment: Thank you @Morag for the response. Even if I hardcode (16 characters) and place it in the field, the receiver is still getting 32 chars with 16 blank spaces padded.

Comment: @Mitu. I have just tested this out for myself and it does appear that the queue manager will always blank pad this field. So then I checked the IBM Docs (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=descriptor-applidentitydata-mqchar32-mqmd) and it says "If a null character is present, the null and any following characters are converted to blanks by the queue manager." So you must alter the receiving application to handle blank padded instead of null padded data.

Comment: Understood. Thank you @Morag! Appreciate your response!